# xcodebuild seems to sign code differently than Xcode's 'Export' option

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild

I've got the following in our build file:

```
 xcodebuild \
            -allowProvisioningUpdates \
            -allowProvisioningDeviceRegistration \
            -exportArchive \
            -archivePath "$archivePath" \
            -exportOptionsPlist "$plistPath" \
            -exportPath $exportPath
```

Assume that `$archivePath`, `$exportPath` and `$plistPath` are all valid. The produced .app bundle seems to pass when the following is run on the build machine:

`spctl --assess --verbose=4 /path/to.app`

This returns "accepted"

However, deploying this .app bundle on another mac results in the OS complaining "This app is damaged, move to trash". I've tried tuning / changing build options but that didn't help. `spctl` reported that the bundle had `a sealed resource is missing or invalid`.

Finally, simply using the Export Archive option in Xcode ("Developer ID") worked! It was a simply an issue with codesigning (I `codesign -vvvv`).Both machines returned "accepted" when checked against `spctl`.

The question is - what is Xcode doing differently? I could try and code sign a second time after xcodebuild finishes producing the bundle but that doesn't sound right. How can I make xcodebuild behave as Xcode?